# Embedded data from RestApi

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

My data comes from REST API like this:

```
customers:[
    id:3,
    name:"Joue",
    currency:{
        id:5
        iso_code:"BDT"
    }

]
```

My model:

```
App.Customer = DS.Model.extend({
        name: DS.attr('string'),
        currency: DS.attr('string')

});
```

i populated a select box with the availabe currencies and now i want to select by "id" 5.
Since currency is embedded and its interpreted as string i cant access it.
As far as i know embedded records are no longer supported in ember-data 1.0.

do i have to rewrite my REST Api and get rid of the relationships or there is a workaround .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create a custom serializer for the data.

Using your data (slightly modified, since the json isn't valid, and I'm guessing that's just cause it was hand written?)

```
{
    customers:[
     {
      id:3,
      name:"Joue",
      currency:{
        id:5,
        iso_code:"BDT"
      }
    }
   ]
}
```

Here's a serializer for that particular response type (read more about it here https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md)

```
App.CustomerSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  extractArray: function(store, type, payload, id, requestType) {
    var customers = payload.customers,
        currencies = [];

    customers.forEach(function(cust) {
      var currency = cust.currency;
      delete cust.currency;
      if(currency){
        currencies.push(currency);
        cust.currency = currency.id;
      }
    });

    payload = { customers:customers, currencies: currencies };

    return this._super(store, type, payload, id, requestType);
  }
});
```

And your models defined with a relationship

```
App.Customer = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    currency: DS.belongsTo('currency')
});

App.Currency = DS.Model.extend({
    iso_code: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Example:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/535/edit

Comment: thank you! do i have to write serializer for each of my models, or it can be something more univesal? The date comes from the REST API in the same structure. Most of the payloads with objects just like in my example.

Comment: You can definitely make it more generic and change it to `ApplicationSerializer`.

Comment: if i remove the serializer and i handle the currency attribute as obj. (currency: DS.attr() -- as torazaburo suggested ) i have the same result: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/539/edit. Were are the benefits of the relations?

Comment: Record caching, the ability to query the store for currencies/types.

Comment: If you never plan on using the currencies outside of the customer, like they really are just a property that lives on the customer, they are perfectly fine not being a relationship, but a nested property.

Comment: Why you would go to all this trouble simply to represent an object within a model is totally behind me, why this is the accepted answer is even more incomprehensible.

Comment: Why set up ember data if you're just going to mix and match it with pojos?  Setting currency.iso_code using your route wouldn't mark the customer model as dirty.  What if he wanted to make them async models and just include an id for the currency type and avoid multiple calls to the back end for the same currency type. get/set won't work on currency object using a pojo.

Comment: Loosely coupled model definitions are far more descriptive and useful than a pojo.

Answer (score 0):

`currency` is not "embedded", it's just an object. Don't declare it as a string in your model:

```
currency: DS.attr()
```

You say you want to "select" by `id`--what do you actually want to do? You can access the properties of `currency` directly:

```
{{! handlebars }}
Your currency id is {{currency.id}}.

// Javascript
id = model.get('currency.id');
```

No need for additional complexity involving serializers or additional models. However, you need to be careful when changing currency id, since

```
model.set('currency.id', 6)
```

will not dirty the model and it won't save. You'll need to also incant

```
model.notifyPropertyChange('currency')
```