# Emberjs - Calling directly nested resource's URL

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have merged together from this two problem ([How to pass model in Nested routes - emberjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23913314/how-to-pass-model-in-nested-routes-emberjs) and [Embedded data from RestApi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23878688/embedded-data-from-restapi)) a JsBin example: http://jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/544

It works fine if you navigate customers-> info -> contact, but it will break if one calls directly a customer's contact eg.:http://jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/544#/customers/3/contact

*Error while loading route: customer.contact Cannot set property 'store' of undefined TypeError: Cannot set property 'store' of undefined*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do a request for a single record, it uses a different serializer endpoint and expects the data in a different format.  The format it expects is:

```
{
  customer: {
    id: 1,
    currency:1
  },
  currencies: [
    {
      id:1,
      prop: 'foo'
    }
  ]
}
```

And the endpoint in the serializer is `extractSingle`.  Feel free to extract out the portions of `extractArray` that are similar and share those.

Pretending your payload is:

```
  {
    customer:{
      id:3,
      name:"Joue",
      currency:{
        id:5,
        iso_code:"BDT"
      }
    } 
  }
```

Your `extractSingle` would be

```
  extractSingle: function(store, type, payload, id) {
    var customer = payload.customer,
        currencies = [];


    var currency = customer.currency;
    delete customer.currency;
    if(currency){
      currencies.push(currency);
      customer.currency = currency.id;
    }

    payload = { customer:customer, currencies: currencies };

    return this._super(store, type, payload, id);
  }
```

Here's the example, with a response for customer 3

http://jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/545#/customers/3/contact

your property name should match inside the model, and the root name (currencies here) should be the plural version of the type of record it is.

```
{
  customer: {
    id: 1,
    default_currency:1
  },
  currencies: [
    {
      id:1,
      prop: 'foo'
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: kingpin2k: thank you again!! what if i have "default_currency" instead of "currency". do i have to camelCased it? in my app everything fine, only if i have default_currency = DS.belongsTo('currency'), then goes it wrong. I couldnt find any differencies. Prob. im gonna setup a JsBin for this too.